# How to import a rule into another rule in sass?

Tags: css, sass

If I have this

```
.base {
    color:red;
}

.variation1 {
    color:red;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

How can I change it to something like

```
.base {
    color:red;
}

.variation1 {
    import @.base
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

in sass? I basically don't want to repeat the base stuff, I want to import its properties.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Mixin**

You can create a [`mixin`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins) to create reusable chunks of CSS. This helps you avoid repetitive code.

I would suggest a more semantic naming system compared to the sample below.

```
@mixin base {
  color: red;
}

.base {
  @include base;
}

.variation1 {
  @include base;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

For more information about the mixin directive check out this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-the-mixin-directive/) on Sitepoint.

**Extend**

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/) elaborates nicely on the `extend` feature that can also be used but it's got some quirks to it.

```
.base {
  @include base;
}

.variation1 {
  @extend .base;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

> - It expands all nested selectors as well
> - It cannot extend a nested selector
> - You can't extend inside a media query to a selector defined outside the media query

*From [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/)*

Comment: That is an option but apparently it extends all nested selectors as well. That might not always be the desired outcome but I'll update my post to make a reference to it.

Comment: Can I do this to one rule of the `base` only? For example, `base` requires the margin to be 10px, and I want to copy that rule only to `variation1` without the other rules.